# Doctrine Inheritance: Update Entity Fields

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I'm trying to use InheritanceType("JOINED") for some entities of an API. Everything seems to work properly until I'm trying to implement my update routine.

I have the following classes: An abstract class `Item` with abstract subclasses `ItemA`, `ItemB` and so on. These classes have subclasses `SubItemA`, `SubItemB` and so on.

Depending on the class of the entity, I need to be able to update different fields since not all child classes have the same fields. For this I have one form per child class. This is my function:

```
public function update(Request $request, $itemId): JsonResponse
{
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

    $item = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Item::class)->findOneBy(['id' => $itemId]);

    // ... Error Handling ...

    // Get the form of the item child class
    $itemType = get_class($item);
    $formClass = null;
    switch ($itemType) {
        case 'SubItemA':
            $formClass = SubItemAType::class;
            break;
        case 'SubItemB':
            $formClass = SubItemBType::class;
            break;
        // ... Other Item Types ...
    }

    $form = $this->createForm($formClass, $item);

    $form->submit($data);

    // ... Error Handling ...

    $this->entityManager->persist($item);
    $this->entityManager->flush();
}
```

When using this function, I can update all fields that are inherited from the `Item` class. But fields that only exist on the `SubItemA` class are not persisted to the database, even though `get_class($item)` returns `SubItemA`, which makes me think the entity should be treated as `SubItemA` instead of `Item`.

For testing purposes I created a separate repository for my SubItemA class and changed my `getRepository` call to fetch that repository:

```
public function update(Request $request, $itemId): JsonResponse
{
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

    $item = $this->entityManager->getRepository(SubItemA::class)->findOneBy(['id' => $itemId]);

    // ... Error Handling ...

    // Get the form of the item child class
    $itemType = get_class($item);
    $formClass = null;
    switch ($itemType) {
        case 'SubItemA':
            $formClass = SubItemAType::class;
            break;
        case 'SubItemB':
            $formClass = SubItemBType::class;
            break;
        // ... Other Item Types ...
    }

    $form = $this->createForm($formClass, $item);

    $form->submit($data);

    // ... Error Handling ...

    $this->entityManager->persist($item);
    $this->entityManager->flush();
}
```

Using this code I am able to update all fields of the entity, even those that are defined only on the `SubItemA` class. But of course this code would not work for entities of type `SubItemB` and so on. To make this work dynamically with all my child types I tried the following:

```
public function update(Request $request, $itemId): JsonResponse
{
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

    $item_tmp = $this->entityManager->getRepository(Item::class)->findOneBy(['id' => $itemId]);
    $item = $this->entityManager->getRepository(get_class($item_tmp))->findOneBy(['id' => $itemId]);

    // ... Error Handling ...

    // Get the form of the item child class
    $itemType = get_class($item);
    $formClass = null;
    switch ($itemType) {
        case 'SubItemA':
            $formClass = SubItemAType::class;
            break;
        case 'SubItemB':
            $formClass = SubItemBType::class;
            break;
        // ... Other Item Types ...
    }

    $form = $this->createForm($formClass, $item);

    $form->submit($data);

    // ... Error Handling ...

    $this->entityManager->persist($item);
    $this->entityManager->flush();
}
```

I realize that this code introduces overhead by fetching the same entity twice. But sadly it does not even work. Again, only fields from the `Item` class are being updated. It seems like after loading the entity for the first time it gets cached and associated with the `Item` repository in some way which prevents me from actually re-fetching it through my `SubItemA` repository.

I don't understand enough about the inner workings of Doctrine to figure out what's going on here. What is the recommended way of doing updates like this? Do I need different API points for all of my child classes?

---

**Edit**
I just figured out that if I change my "intermediate" abstract class `ItemA` to be non-abstract, everything works properly with the first code. So the abstract intermediate class seems to play a role as well...

Comment: Not sure how this can work. Your code assumes that the `id` of all entities are unique, in other words an object of type `SubItemA` will never have the same `id` as `SubItemB`, etc. You didn't show code for your entities but of course you would have to enforce this somehow.

Comment: @ehymel As far as I know Doctrine takes care of this because I'm using the table inheritance features.

Comment: Got it. Untested idea: in your switch branches just re-define `$item` in each `case`, except now find by id for that specific subItem. Then that becomes the `$item` you pass to the createForm() method.